# Testing content providers with ProviderTestCase2

Tags: android, testing, android-contentprovider

I am trying to test my content provider following the snippet in this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35680611/12652258

The post mentions that the **Test must not be run with AndroidJUnit4 runner -Test of course must be run as android instrumented test**

How do I achieve this ?

1: Running  an instrumented test without using AndroidJUnit4 runner ?

2: Where do I place the test files in my project? In the **test** folder or **androidTest** folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

You place your files in the **androidTest** directory.

Remove the annotation
`@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)`

Make sure your method is prefixed with the word **test**. Everything should run just fine if you follow this answer given in this post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35680611/12652258